# Skin modifier not work for entire mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I created spider web using curves. Then I joined all curves using CTRL + j.
Then I wanted to apply "skin modifier" to create mash.
Skin was added only to one line as shown in the picture. How to fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: ok, file is there :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to mark all the vertices as root.  So..

1. Select `NurbsPath.005`
2. Get into `Edit Mode`.
3. Hit `a` twice.
4. Goto the `Skin Modifier` Panel and hit `Mark Root`.
5. While they're still selected, you can hit `Ctrl + A` to tweak the thickness of the web.